# Cloning command Xbox One

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to clone a square from original coordinates [(-666, 15, -339)(-671, 10, -335)] along the x-axis by 6 spaces each time. I want the y- and z-axis to remain the same each time.

My thought was `/clone -666 15 -339 -671 10 -335 -6 ~ ~ replace`. However it keeps trying to clone it out of the loaded chunk.

I'm trying to create a command block that once activated will just copy the space around it over and over in a straight line.

Comment: Firstly, you should always write the lower coordinates first. You can get all kinds of weird results otherwise.

Comment: Is the area loaded where you want to clone from?

Comment: Yes, and after sleeping on it I realized my original cordinates are not going to work as they need to be relative to the command block each time. What I'm going for is an infanant road kind of deal, just on a much larger scale, than typical 5x5 square you find. The question above is for my test area the end product Im replicating is about 5 times larger.

Comment: I once made an infinite cloning machine with just two blocks. So it shouldn't be too hard. Do you think that you can answer it yourself after a bit of research?

Comment: Cloning syntax is `/clone <xyzlower> <xyzhigher> <xyzdestination> replace move` and now you somehow have to power it. Repeating command block would be possible, but would create an infinitely increasing amount of lag, so you need a different way.

Comment: I did a good bit of reseach before posting but ever syntax i found was invalid for xbox-one. I ended up doing it manualy for this part. Id still like to figure out something that would work for this. My original idea was to have the comand block clond with the chunk each time so that i could easly kill the comand by cuting power. That was why i was needing each peice moved in relation to the newly created peice. I just cant get the relative cordinates correct. I realize my orignal post wasnt quite as detailed. Thats what happens when your half asleep lol.

Comment: Look at the wiki. It has command references for all minecraft editions.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond! I just figured this out using another command, completly by mistake, typed the wrong key by mistake and it preformed what i was trying to do here.

Comment: Then you can write that as an answer and mark it as accepted to indicate that your problem was solved. It can also help people who have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

So the command to copy a location relative to the execution location (command blocks location or yours if you use command window) is as follows: `/clone ~x ~y ~z ~x ~y ~z ~x ~y ~z`. Count the number of blocks from your execution location and use that for your x, y, and z coordinates.